# "DELETE FROM locations ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT" 1 on knex.js not working

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js, knex.js

I try write this command:

```
DELETE FROM locations ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
```

on knex.js.
I write this code:

```
knex('locations').delete().orderBy('id', 'desc').limit(1).toString()
```

But it return

```
DELETE FROM locations
```

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `LIMIT` is not supported by Postgres and Knex is supposed to be compatible with both MySQL and PostgreSQL. See [GitHub issue](https://github.com/knex/knex/issues/96):

> [...] this syntax isn't supported in Postgres, so that might be a bit unexpected if it's possible in one database and not another [...]

> Please open a new feature request if you need this functionality to be changed.

It was mentioned there that it works since 0.6 but I can't verify that, it seems still to be not working, and that seems to be a design choice. (Personally I find this quite problematic because there is no error, you just silently get everything deleted.)

The only way to handle a `DELETE LIMIT` statement would be as raw query with [`knex.raw`](http://knexjs.org/guide/raw.html#raw-queries) then.